# Rails 4: Find all entries with no parents in has_many :though self-referential join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, self-reference

So my setup is I have Categories, and a `category` can have many parents and many children through the self-referential join table `category_relationships`. Using the below, this all works great when creating and retrieving those relationships.

What I'd like to do now though is, find categories that don't have any parents (basically all top-level categories).

I've tried a few different `where.not` type implementations, but am just not coming up with the right expression.

**category.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)      not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  # CategoryRelationships (Parents & Children)
  # ==========================================================================================================  
    has_many                        :parent_child_relationships,
                                      class_name:     "CategoryRelationship",
                                      foreign_key:    :child_id, 
                                      inverse_of:     :parent,
                                      dependent:      :destroy

    has_many                        :parents,
                                      through:        :parent_child_relationships,
                                      source:         :parent

    has_many                        :child_parent_relationships,
                                      class_name:     "CategoryRelationship",
                                      foreign_key:    :parent_id,
                                      inverse_of:     :child,
                                      dependent:      :destroy

    has_many                        :children,
                                      through:        :child_parent_relationships, 
                                      source:         :child

end
```

**category_relationships.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: category_relationships
#
#  child_id   :integer          not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  parent_id  :integer          not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class CategoryRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Parent (Category)
  # ========================================================================================================== 
    belongs_to                      :parent,
                                      class_name:     "Category",
                                      inverse_of:     :parent_child_relationships

  # Child (Category)
  # ========================================================================================================== 
    belongs_to                      :child,
                                      class_name:     "Category",
                                      inverse_of:     :child_parent_relationships

  # Validations
  # ========================================================================================================== 
    validates                       :parent, 
                                      presence:       true

    validates                       :child, 
                                      presence:       true

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with:

```
Category.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN category_relationships ON categories.id = category_relationships.child_id").where("category_relationships.child_id IS NULL")
```

Though, I'm not sure how efficient it is or if there is a better method as I've heard that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` can be costly on larger data sets.